# IE7 Selectbox options disable

Tags: javascript, prototype

I have an avaliable list of selectbox and I can't change the options. In Selectbox there are some disabled options but IE7 does not pay attention to the disabled property ;)

Which will be the best way to controll disabled options?

Thanks

Comment: How about sharing a concise version of your HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the DOM to remove the disabled options from the select element completely. That's about all you can do.